# Fetch Selected Fields in WP_Query Class in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to fetch selected fields in WP_Query Class in WordPress.
I didn't find any argument for the same.

```
args=array('tag' => $tagname,'showposts'=>$no_of_post,'caller_get_posts'=>1);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I need only title and description of the post.
How to pass selected field in **WP_Query** function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really understand the question, but I will try to answer .

First of all, WP_Query is not a function, it is a class.

So after you do `$my_query = new WP_Query($args);` the class object is available.

That means that after setting up the data , you just use it normally if you want a loop for example :

```
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    $my_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
   ... continue your loop
```

or `$post->ID` after setting the post data ( or `$post->title` )

Or access it directly :

`$my_query->post->ID`

All the post details are available normally, But I am not sure what you mean about `description`, do you mean `excerpt` ??

Comment: I know that WP_Query return whole object and i can fetch data using it but i want only certain data like post id to return in WP_Query class.is it possible?

Comment: I do not really understand why when you can access it with `$post->title`, but you can always complicate things by use either the  [Return Fields Parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters) or filters (same link ) and specifically  [the posts_where filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where)  on the same query.

Comment: The link to the Return fields parameter posted by @ObmerkKronen has changed. The correct link is now https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter